# Accessing an element from one HTML to another HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

On my `index.html` page, I ask the user to enter their input. This then creates a button with their input on it. Clicking on the button will lead to `inside_goal.html`. I want that page to have a heading equal to the name of the button.

This is the code for asking for user input:

```
<body>
  <h1 id="home_header" style="font-family: optima; text-align: center"> Nancy Dong </h1>
  <div id="enter.goal">
    <form id="subBox" onsubmit="createButton(); return false;">
      <input type="text" , id="goal">
      <input type="submit" , value="Enter Goal">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="space_holder" style="top = 50px; left: 50px;">
  </div>
  <script src='timer.js'>
  </script>
  <script src='name.js'></script>
</body>
```

This is the code for how the button is created with the user input name on it (within `index.html`):

```
function createButton() {
  var x = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  x.className = "second";
  x.id = "first";
  var name = document.querySelector("#goal").value;
  var t = document.createTextNode(name);
  x.appendChild(t);
  document.getElementById("space_holder").appendChild(x);
  var insideclass = document.getElementsByClassName("second");
  insideclass[counter].innerHTML = `<input type="button" onclick="location.href='inside_goal.html';" value="${name}" />`;
  counter = counter + 1;
  document.querySelector("#goal").value = "";
```

Now the problem is I can't find a way to put `#goal` into `inside_goal.html`. I have tried:

```
document.getElementById("h1").innerHTML =  $('#goal').load("index.html");
```

but it only prints `[object Object]`

I've also tried:

```
$.get( "index.html", function(test) {
  $( "#h1" ).html( test );
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

How can I only access the `#goal` part of the `index.html` and not have the entire HTML page displayed on `inside_goal.html`?

Comment: read the documentation for load. `Loading Page Fragments`

Comment: Link for that is here: https://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using jquery load() wrong.  if #goal is in the 1st html file (index.html) then it should be:

```
$("selector_in_2nd_page").load("index.html #goal");
```